# Mailing_send_test - job_id is not valid

Tags: mailing, mosaico, testing

I am having a "Error in call to Mailing_send_test : job_id is not valid : 14" when I send test email in Mosaico (to one email or to a group) whereas email settings are working perfectly.

My mailing id seems to be 16, 14 have been deleted weeks ago. Why the test functions are stuck with job_id 14 ? How to release it ?

Any idea ?

- Civicrm : 5.5.1 - Wordpress 4.9.8
- Mosaico : 2.0-beta4.1528762072
- FlexMailer : 0.2-alpha5

EDIT :
If I don't use mosaico, test mails and mailing are working perfectly.

This is the log related to the error :

```
[info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
( 
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => exceptionHandler
    )

[code] => -3
[message] => DB Error: constraint violation
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_event_queue (job_id , email_id , contact_id , hash ) VALUES ( 14 ,  97 ,  97 , 'beba286cbb5ec019' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mailing_job` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_event_queue (job_id , email_id , contact_id , hash ) VALUES ( 14 ,  97 ,  97 , 'beba286cbb5ec019' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mailing_job` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_event_queue (job_id , email_id , contact_id , hash ) VALUES ( 14 ,  97 ,  97 , 'beba286cbb5ec019' )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mailing_job` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]"]
)
```

Comment: Do you have any customizations done on your site? 14 might be the result of those changes?

Comment: The website is quite basic, not a lot of plugins neither components, only mail report and members, everything was fine before and I realized this issue only recently. Finally this is also impacting a complete mailing campaign. "Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Echec, Error message: job_id is not valid : 14"

Comment: You could find more info from the log files placed under `ConfigAndLog` folder. If possible paste the backtrace here.

Answer (score 0):

I found out when I uninstall nz.co.fuzion.transactional plugin it is working.

I can't reinstall it to be sure it's the real cause because the plugin setup want to create an exiting DB ! If some developers used to work with Fuzion can help on that it could be great.